# Codeigniter session data only available after refresh

Tags: codeigniter

I'm setting userdata in codeigniter when the site first loads, i'm doing this in a helper file called `ipdata`

it set's the data, however everything on my website that calls that data, doesn't work until the user refreshes the page they are on.

I'm not sure if i'm doing this the right way, but basically what I was trying to achieve was

when a user goes on my website, it runs a script that uses an online API that returns information based on that users IP. For example the users `country`

This way i can provide data from my DB that is relevant to where the user is located.

My helper file `ipdata` looks like this :

```
function ipdata ()
{

$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->library('session');


if ($ci->session->userdata('longitude') !== FALSE) {


}else{
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/XXXXX?api-key=XXXXXX"));


$timezone = $details->time_zone->name;
$city = $details->city;
$country = $details->country_name;
  $longitude = $details->longitude;
$latitude = $details->latitude;
$regioncode = $details->country_code . "-" . $details->region_code;

$ci->session->set_userdata('longitude', $longitude);
$ci->session->set_userdata('latitude', $latitude);

$ci->session->set_userdata('timezone', $timezone);
$ci->session->set_userdata('city', $city);   
$ci->session->set_userdata('regioncode', $regioncode);   
$ci->session->set_userdata('country', $country);  



}
}
```

previously, on every controller and view, i was running

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/XXXXX?api-key=XXXXXX"));
```

but have been hitting the request threshold by ipdata, so it kept causing problems when the API could not be reached, due to me hitting my quota.

so I wanted to make it so it only get's called once, on site load - then i can use the sessiondata throughout the site instead.

Is this the right way to do this?

Is there any way I can acheive setting the session data, without the user needing to refresh the site?

Comment: let's say `ipdata()` is called before method `foo`. are you saying that in method foo, if you `print_r($_SESSION)` you don't see your session vars until refresh? how exactly are you testing your assertion? because as long as ipdata is called before attempting to get the session var, the data should be avail down the line

Comment: Yes, ipdata() is being run on a view/header.php file - I only see the session data after refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the variables in the all controllers, need to create core controller in core folder of you project.
In core folder create a php document named "MY_Controller.php". remember that the name should be as it is written i.e. MY_Controller

now add following code in MY_Controller.php

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');

        $data = [];
        $data['timezone'] = '';
        $data['city'] = '';
        $data['longitude'] = '';
        $data['country'] = '';
        $data['longitude'] = '';
        $data['latitude'] = '';
        $data['regioncode'] = '';

        $this->timezone = '';
        $this->city = '';
        $this->country = '';
        $this->longitude = '';
        $this->latitude = '';
        $this->regioncode= '';

        if ($this->session->userdata('longitude') == FALSE) {
            $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/86.178.64.129?api-key=427202b10e928e264b7a49cbae08ba636013e7059708a9e4da06ef7f"));

            $data['timezone'] = $details->time_zone->name ? $details->time_zone->name : '';
            $data['city'] = $details->city ? $details->city : '';
            $data['country'] = $details->country_name ? $details->country_name : '';
            $data['longitude'] = $details->longitude ? $details->longitude : '';
            $data['latitude'] = $details->latitude ? $details->latitude : '';
            $data['regioncode'] = $details->region_code ? $details->country_code . "-" . $details->region_code : '';

            // passing variables for all function in the same controller
            $this->timezone = $data['timezone'];
            $this->city = $data['city'];
            $this->country = $data['country'];
            $this->longitude = $data['longitude'];
            $this->latitude = $data['latitude'];
            $this->regioncode= $data['regioncode'];
        }
        $this->load->vars($data);  // passing data to all views 
    }
}
```

I was missing "__" in constructor of MY_Controller, that's why we were not able to access data, Now update MY_Controller as above given.

Now let say your new controller in controller folder is NewController.php
So you have to extend your core controller there to access variables.
for examples

```
<?php

class NewController extends MY_Controller{

    function construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        echo $this->city;
        echo $this->timezone;
    }
}
```

Now you are free to use all the variables from anywhere, You need to just extend the MY_Controller at the place of CI_Controller and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this could be an issue as I have several controllers that i'm using and referencing the session data, would it be wise to add the above code to every controller?

Comment: For that you need to create a core controller in core folder of your project. and put the above code in that core controller names as MY_Controller and then you have to extend that MY_Controller where ever you want to use the variables. for that you can see this -> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Thank you, i've done this, but in the controller (after i've extended it) when i try to echo $this->regioncode; I get the error :  Message: Undefined property: Home::$regioncode

Comment: same in the view, getting error: undefined variable $city. I'm using 2.2.6 version of codeigniter, i havn't been able to upgrade.. could this be why?

Comment: I think your default constructor doesn't contain this code -> parent::__construct(); make sure you are writing this in constructor -> parent::__construct();

Comment: Even with that, it seems none of the variables are being loaded, is there a way to check that the custom controller is being loaded? it's hard to know what could be causing the issue

Comment: Even when i clear cache , it still not working :( - i even tried it on mobile network

Comment: Print something in the if statement and see if it prints the echo statement. If it is not printing that means the if statement is preventing to set the variables

Comment: Yeah I just tried that, and it doesn't - so i am thinking maybe the custom core file isn't being loaded ?

Comment: The problem is with your codeigniter version. I found something which can help you with codeigniter version 2.2.6. follow this link -> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Hi mate, I just spent the last few hours upgrading to the latest version of codeigniter, but i am still having issues, it seems that it's not loading any of the variables set in MY_controller, and even when echoing some code in the core/MY_controller.php file, it's not showing anywhere, so i have a feeling that the controller isn't being loaded.. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside if statement replace the condition to this -> if ($this->session->userdata('longitude') == FALSE). Then too if you are getting error. then share me your code somewhere so that i can see it.

Comment: I am still getting undefined variable and Message: Undefined property: Home::$regioncode error when echoing $this->regioncode in controller 'Home' and in views $regioncode. 

http://codepad.org/vg2CXdji - MY_Controller - core/MY_Controller.php
http://codepad.org/z4LUwJea  - Home Controller - controllers/Home.php

Comment: Now copy the MY_Controller part in your MY_Controller part. then it will work. A working code, you can see here, I made a fresh project for you -> http://demo1.geniesoftsystem.com/newweb/ci2/index.php/home/

Comment: got it! thank you so much, it seems to be working! god bless you

Comment: MY_Controller.php : "http://codepad.org/FN5URBUR",                                
Home.php : "http://codepad.org/mAeWWzYr",                                          myview.php : "http://codepad.org/SZdalonA"                                                     
Result : http://demo1.geniesoftsystem.com/newweb/ci2/index.php/home/

Answer (score 0):

By using `$ci->load->library('session');` and create `$_SESSION['is_ipdata_called'] = false;` with default value, so if the user visit for the first time it return false

```
function ipdata (!$_SESSION['is_ipdata_called'])
{
  $_SESSION['is_ipdata_called'] = true;
  ...
}
```

It will no longer be called if the user refreshes many times.